# Tree-planting problem with pagoda functions (from PROMYS)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

This question has been asked before, at least twice by people who were trying to cheat on the PROMYS Europe 2020 Application, and once in a [question closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586306/tree-math-problem) because the OP showed no effort. I haven't been able to solve it, so I'm going to to ask it again.  PROMYS applications have closed, and I hope the effort shown below is enough to keep this question from being closed.

> The Mathematical Forest is grown in a two-dimensional plane, where
>   trees can only grow on points with integer coordinates. To start with,
>   there are no trees at all. The foresters plant the first tree at
>   $(0,0)$. Each year, they carry out tree planting according to the
>   following rule. If there is a tree on the point (,) but there are
>   no trees on the points $(m+1,n)$ and $(m,n+1)$, then they can choose
>   to remove the tree on $(m,n)$ and plant new trees on the points
>   $(m,n+1)$ and $(m+1,n)$. For an integer $k\geq1$, the $k$th diagonal
>   consists of all points $(m,n)$ with $m+n=k−1$. Is it possible for the
>   foresters to arrange their planting so that eventually there are no
>   trees on the first $2$ diagonals? What about the first $3$ diagonals? 
>   $4$ diagonals? Can you generalize?

It's easy to get to a position with no trees on the first two diagonals.  (It only takes $4$ plantings.)  I can prove it's impossible to reach a position with no trees on the first $4$ diagonals, and I believe it's impossible to reach a position with no trees on the first $3$ diagonals, but I can't prove it.

For the $k=4$ case, I used a pagoda function, as in a peg solitaire problem.  For $k=1,2,3,\dots$ define the potential of a tree on the $k$th diagonal as $\frac1{2^{k-1}}$, and the potential of the forest as the sum of the potentials of all the trees in it.  When a tree of potential $\frac1{2^{k-1}}$ is removed, it is replaced by $2$ trees of potential $\frac1{2^k}$ so the potential of the forest never changes.  Initially, the potential of the forest is $1$.

Since there are $k$ trees on diagonal $k$, the potential of all points beyond the fourth diagonal is $$\sum_{k=5}^\infty\frac k{2^{k-1}}=\frac34<1,$$ so it is impossible that there are no trees on the first $4$ diagonals.

The potential of the fourth diagonal is $\frac12$, so this argument doesn't show that it's impossible to have no trees on the first $3$ diagonals.  I've done a lot of experimenting, though, and I believe that the statement is true.  (I even wrote a little computer game so I could experiment quickly.)  The best I've been able to do is to get down to one man on the third diagonal.
[image] 
The black circles are trees eligible for removal, and the gray circles are other trees.  You can see that there is a "traffic jam" in front of the lone tree on diagonal $3$, and there seems to be no way to clear it.

I've been trying to come up with an argument that reflects this traffic jam, but I haven't been at all successful. We know that after $n$ removals there are $n+1$ trees, and I've been trying to prove somehow that they can't all be sufficiently far from the origin to allow all trees to get past diagonal $3$, but I haven't come close.

In the diagram above, if the tree at $(1,1)$ were moved to $(0,2)$, and the tree at $(1,2)$ were moved to $(2,0)$, then it would be possible to remove the tree at $(0,2)$, emptying the second diagonal.  In the fictitious position, we still have one tree on diagonal $2$ and two on diagonal $3$.

So, I think an argument along the lines I was trying cannot just be concerned with the distance from the origin; it must somehow take into account how the trees interfere with one another.  I haven't been able to do this.

I'd be grateful for solutions, hints, or counterexamples.

I wasn't really sure what tags to attach.  Please add any that seem appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing 1 more observation.

Reveal as much as you need.

> Look at the first column.

$ $

> How many trees can there be in the first column?

$ $

> As per your diagram, there is only 1 tree in the first column. Can we get more?

$ $

> Ditto for the first row.

$ $

> How does that restrict your potential summation?

$ $

> The potential is at most $\frac{1}{8} + 1 - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} =1 $.

But this requires infinitely many years, so it cannot be done.

Comment: Excellent!  The essential point actually led me astray, in a way.     I thought about trying to prove that the trees had to be close to the diagonal, but then I saw that I could put a tree anywhere I wanted in the first row (or column) and abandoned the idea.